# What is the difference between the [copyfile] and the [file-copying] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I was browsing Stack Overflow and came across [Copy a file from one location to another in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851994/copy-a-file-from-one-location-to-another-in-python), it had both [copyfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyfile) and [file-copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) tags. On further research found out that [copyfile] has no usage guidance. It is being used almost in the same cases/situations as [file-copying].

I am aware that some tags are under the burnination process to reduce the number of redundant tags - should [copyfile] also be seen as a candidate for the same? If so how can one suggest the tag for burnination? If not what is the appropriate use for both the tags?

Comment: [copyfile] is the specific name of a commonly used OS and framework function that copies files.  Used on a billion computers, many times a day.  Not all of them, but available in [python] as well so it is relevant for [file-copying].

Comment: @HansPassant Then is it possible to add such a description in for the [copyfile] tag ? because as it currently stands the tag has no usage guidance and from the questions listed under the tag a few of them don't seem to be referring to the function possibly due this. (I too was unsure of its proper use until you pointed out which questions it was intended to be used for)

Comment: Sure, you can propose an edit.  I'd assume that nobody yet found it necessary since it is such a common function.

Comment: @HansPassant Additionally, on Apple platforms, `copyfile()` is a rather special function because it has mechanisms to preserve HFS/APFS-specific metadata when copying files, as well as to convert said metadata to various different forms.

Comment: `copyfile` is also a function in the standard library `shutil` python module

Comment: @HansPassant Why does a function need its own tag? O_o While at it (to anyone), why does file copying need its own tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be a good synonym.

[file-copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) is far superior.  As one example, questions about using `CopyFile()` on Windows might lead to answers that the requested behavior is not available from `CopyFile()` but `SHFileOperation()` should be used instead.

That's why tags should be topical and not simply function names.